# Swagger-ui - Not able to figure out how some features are functioning for Petstore

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have downloaded and browsed to the Swagger-UI dist/index.html file and it has loaded the sample Petstore APIs. However, I am not able to figure out how some features are functioning and hence not able to bring that to my own definition.

1. The sample Petstore shows a "VALID {...}" button at the bottom right hand side. However I don't see that when I navigate to my own API definitions. How do I enable it?
2. When I look up the petstore API specifications being rendered by Swagger-UI `http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json`I am not able to figure out how are they plugging in the section below the Swagger Petstore description.

`Contact the developer`
This is a mailto link with an email address and subject line

`Find out more about Swagger http://swagger.io` doesn't show up either in the petstore json definition or the one that I am using.

Where is the sample picking this up from?

3. When I use the Swagger editor, it interprets the specification in a different way - most significantly showcasing the `terms of use` and `license` information appropriately. Does Swagger-UI not support those properties? Do I need to enable something in Swagger-UI to make them appear?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using the latest version of Swagger, [Swagger Core 1.5](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/tree/v1.5.6) at least, to have these neat features in your own Swagger project.

1. The UI at version > 2.0 comes with the schema validation (the VALID button on the bottom of the page) built-in.

2+3. [The Info object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#info-object) contains all the information needed for rendering `Contact the developer`, license and "More Info" links by the UI.

Comment: MrMister, I am not sure why I need Swagger Core 1.5. I have downloaded Swagger-UI 2.1.4 and am using it simply to generate the UI from my definition. The issue here is #1, 2 and 3 are appearing for the sample petstore api definition  but not for the API definitions that I am writing. If you download Swagger UI 2.1.4 and run it you will be able to see it for yourself.

Comment: Ritwik, running SwaggerUI 2.1.4 locally with the Petstore API definition yields me the VALID{...} button as expected. Are you experiencing something else?
Also, pay attention that Swagger Core and UI are two different beings, and you need to point at the latest OpenAPI  specification (as I linked in my answer) in order to enjoy #2+#3 in the locally-running UI.